# Sampling a uniformly distributed point INSIDE a hypersphere?

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, algorithms

There is [a simple algorithm to pick a random point ON an $n$-dimensional hypersphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136314/what-is-a-good-method-to-find-random-points-on-the-n-sphere-when-n-is-large).

Is there one to sample a point from inside it? (Sampling points from a hypercube and rejecting them if they are not inside the hypersphere would scale extremely poorly with $n$, as the vast majority of points would be rejected)

Comment: Mark Meckes's accepted answer to that question answers this one too: take a random point on the $n+1$-dimensional hypersphere and drop two coordinates.

Comment: @NateEldredge $n+2$ perhaps, since we want to keep $n$ numbers? It's not super-obvious that this will be uniformly distributed though.

Comment: I think $n+1$ is correct; remember that the $n+1$-hypersphere is the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$. It may not be super-obvious but I think it's a fairly straightforward calculus exercise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choose a uniform point $X$ on the unit hypersphere, then multiply it by $U^{1/n}$ where $U \sim U(0,1)$ is independent of $X$.